# installing sphinx on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sphinx

I installed MySQL with `apt-get`

Ubuntu separates the mysql files to the following locations:

```
/usr/bin/mysql
/var/lib/mysql
/var/log/mysql
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Following the instructions from sphinx document:

```
$ ./configure
```

`--prefix`, which specifies where to install Sphinx; such as `--prefix=/usr/local/sphinx` (all of the examples use this prefix)

`--with-mysql`, which specifies where to look for MySQL include and library files, if auto-detection fails;

---

I get the following error:

```
checking whether to compile with MySQL support... yes
configure: error: invalid MySQL root directory '/usr/bin'; neither bin/mysql_config, nor include/ and lib/ were found there
```

---

Where should I tell it to look for MySQL?

```
$ ./configure --with-mysql=WHICH PLACE?
```

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the `libmysqlclient-dev` package otherwise `mysql_config`, part of what you missing based on the traceback you posted, won't be on your machine.

```
shell$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

You can use the `which` command to locate `mysql_config` after installing the package

```
shell$ which mysql_config
```

On my Ubuntu machine it's `/usr/bin/mysql_config`

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch`?  Not sure why you're trying to compile it from source instead of using the existing Ubuntu package.

Comment: I know the method you provide, and it works. But I want try the compile method.

Comment: Also, the latest binaries with this method are version 0.9.9 and the latest sphinx is 2.0.3

Comment: Here is the deb install for 2.0.3.  https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/sphinxsearch